# GEE kalman-filter

Tags: google-earth-engine, kalman-filter

Is there an implemantation of Kalman filter in Google earth engine?

If not has anyone code it on their JS api or could give me a hint what could be used instead?

Have extensivly searched the documention and web but often miss something